# WordPress Function to Change Child Page Title to Match Parent

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site where by global page template (from Elementor) pulls in the correct title for the page.

However, for my individual WooCommerce products (pages), I'd simply like the title 'PRODUCTS' to be set as the page title. I'm looking for a PHP or JS snippet to replace the page title on any pages that are 'children of Products'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the [`the_title` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title)

You should just be able to put a simple `if` condition in there with the parent page ID, something like this perhaps?

```
function replace_product_child_title( $title, $id = null ){
    global $post; // Grab the current WP_Post object
    $product_page_id = 12345; // Put the ID of your "Products" page here

    // See if this post is a direct child of Products
    if( $post->post_parent == $product_page_id ){
        // If it is, override the title
        $title = "PRODUCTS";
    }

    // Always return the title
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'replace_product_child_title', 10, 2 );
```